# Existence of a minimum [basic analysis]

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\neq \emptyset$ be a finite set of $\mathbb{N}^2$. What is an efficient argument to show that $\min \limits _{(x,y)\in A}x+y$ always exists?

**My attempt**

Since $A$ is finite, the image of $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=x+y$ must also be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, thus compact. But every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a minimum.

Comment: Every finite subset of $\Bbb N$ has a least value. This can be taken axiomatically or proven through different means such as an induction

Comment: In this case you don't even need the assumption that $A$ is finite, as per FShrike's comment above. In general though it's also true that any finite subset of a totally ordered set has a minimum element, so you could argue that way.

Comment: This is false if $A = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is finite then there exists a subset $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ that is closed and bounded (compact) such that $$A \subset B$$

Looking at $f(x,y)=x+y$ over $B$, since $f$ is continious over $B$ which is compact then by [Weierstrass's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) ,
$f$ has minimum and maximum in $B$, thus $f$ over $A$ also has minimum and maximum.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think it is efficient to use $B\subset \mathbb R^2$ and the continuity of $f$ to show the result.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? are you performing a computational task?

Comment: I didn't mean to say that your answer was wrong, and sorry if I sounded rude. By "efficient" I meant the most direct way to prove the result. In my question, $f: \mathbb N^2\to\mathbb R$ is precisely defined as $x+y$. Then $Im(f)$ must be finite, thus compact. This shows the existence of a minimum.

Comment: I was trying to understand your question better lol, I think your attempt is correct since the image is compact.
However, in case your image is not compact for example $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ over $\mathbb{N}$ I don't think you solution holds up.

Comment: Thank you for the considerations

Comment: I wonder how many times you need to use the fact that a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a minimum in order to prove all the needed facts about topology, compactness, continuity, etc. For the OP, all is needed is: 1. image of a finite set is finite and 2. a finite set of real numbers has a minimum.